# Azure managed identity performance

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

Is there any experience with Azure Managed Identity performance vs let's say basic authentication.
I am testing managed identity implementation in a microservices environment and observing some degradation compared to basic auth between these services.

Comment: I'm using service managed instance and am seeing fairly noticeable from basic auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I conducted some testing and found that Managed identity performance is same or better than basic authentication.

Comment: Is there any standard testing to compare the performance. Because , I am planning to use Azure Landing Zone and Service Bus connectivity via Managed Identity.  Currently , the Service Bus connection String is used to connect from Java Code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain the scenario a bit more?
What do you mean by performance here? What are you trying to measure?

The biggest advantage of using Azure Managed Identities is that you do NOT have to manage any credentials in your code. You are free from rotating any credentials. You don't have access to the credential, so you cannot accidently leak it either.

Otherwise, Managed identities are same as any other identity in Azure AD. Read more at https://aka.ms/managedidentity

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer. Remove the "Can you please explain the scenario a bit more? What do you mean by performance here? What are you trying to measure?" part and write it underneath this comment.